# Prevent low quality placeholder images being used in search results

Tags: images

On a site that uses low quality placeholder images in the `src` attribute which are then replaced with higher quality images with [LazySizes](https://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/index.html), these low quality images are showing up in search results and don't look very good.

I'm wondering if `X-Robots-Tag "noindex"` was set on these images to remove them from the image index whether that would prevent them from being used as thumbnails or would that just remove them from image searches?

Answer (score 0):

It would remove them from image search, if there are no other links to teh images on your site or any external site.